# Changing Colour of Icon in Wordpress with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress website using the [Dustrial](http://pluginspoint.com/dustrialwp/) theme, and I'm having some issues with changing the colour of the Font Awesome icons in the pre-header bar.

As you can see from the screenshot, I've changed the colour of the icon (.h1-single-top-block i.fa) to #ffffff, but it's being overridden by the code above it (color: #92d050 !important;).

[See linked image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsbNc.jpg)

Now I know !important takes precedence but I can't find the file in which this code is because all it's telling me is (index).

[See linked image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF5oc.png)

If I disable the code for this, the icons do change to white as I want, but I'm struggling to find where the .css file for the bit causing the issue.

[See linked image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpPCt.jpg)

Can anybody help?

EDIT: as you can see from the below link, the Theme Editor in the Wordpress backend is showing the icons to be White, but it's just not working.

[See linked image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFRwG.png)

Also, the (index):237 that is referencing it - where the hell is this file? There is no index.html file in the backend or anything like that.

Comment: Find it in whole project  `.h1-single-top-block i.fa`

Comment: @dalecandela Can you share link of this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't particularly a CSS problem as you understand the way that the cascade works and that newer declarations override previous ones.

It also seems like you know that you need to remove that `(color: #92d050 !important;)` declaration.

In order to find where that declaration is being made; open up the page in Chrome dev tools (other dev tools are likely similar but I use chrome) and focus on the element in question.

[image]

on the right hand side you will see the stylesheets responsible for the styles being applied to each element. If you click on that, you'll see it's full URL and  then be able to get to the declaration.

If the file responsible for the `color: #92d050 !important;` declaration is `index.html` then the file is being inlined. It could be in your `header.php` directly or it could be being inlined from a separate CSS file. You'd have to look at header.php to see this.

Another way around this would be to use a program like atom and do a search through the whole site for the `color: #92d050 !important;` declaration. This will allow yu to find it.

This is a good example of why you should use the !important declaration as as sparingly as possible.

**I have just seen a link to the site**

The overriding declaration is in your index file and is likely in header.php. If you don't see it there directly there should be a reference to some .css files in header.php. The over riding declaration will be in one of these CSS files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - where can I find this Atom?

Comment: You can download atom at atom.io. Make sure the whole site folder is added as a project (File > Add Project Folder)... Then search the whole project folder by simultaneously pressing [command] [shift] [f]

Comment: Here is the header.php code, I don't see any header.php references - https://textuploader.com/1oo5z

Comment: please post the code again if you still haven't solved the problem... The link you posted has expired